# EFCore update related data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

So, I have the following model:

```cs
public class Test
{
    //Test properties
    public ICollection<TestQuestion>? TestQuestions { get; set; }
}

public class TestQuestion
{
    //Test question properties
    public Guid TestId { get; set; }
    public Test? Test { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TestAnswer>? TestQuestions { get; set; }
}

public class TestAnswer
{
    //Test answer properties
    public Guid TestQuestionId { get; set; }
    public TestQuestion? TestQuestion { get; set; }   
}
```

And I want to update the entire test model when I call the Put method of the API. Update in my case is a change in the properties of the test, the properties of the question or the properties of the answer, and Update can also be a new question added to the test or a new answer added to the question. I have created my own solution that works, but I am not sure if it is optimal, it looks like this:

```cs
public async Task Update(Test test)
{
    var newEntity = test;
    var oldEntity = await GetById(test.Id);

    appContext.Tests.Update(newEntity);

    foreach (var question in newEntity.TestQuestions)
    {
        var existingQuestion = oldEntity.TestQuestions.FirstOrDefault(tq => tq.Id == question.Id);

        if (existingQuestion == null)
        {
            await appContext.TestQuestions.AddAsync(question);
            await appContext.TestAnswers.AddRangeAsync(question.TestAnswers);
        }
        else
        {
            appContext.TestQuestions.Update(question);

            foreach (var answer in question.TestAnswers)
            {
                var exsitingAnswer = existingQuestion.TestAnswers.FirstOrDefault(ta => ta.Id == answer.Id);

                if (exsitingAnswer == null)
                    await appContext.TestAnswers.AddAsync(answer);
                else
                    appContext.TestAnswers.Update(answer);
            }
        }
    }
    await appContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I would be happy to hear any comments or advice, thank you in advance for your response.